# Webpack Dev Server works on every browser except Chrome?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I've setup webpack dev server with the following settings, it works fine on Firefox and Safari but won't work on Chrome.

I get this message:

This site can’t be reached

localhost refused to connect.
Search Google for localhost 3005
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

webpack.config.js

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const nodeEnv = process.env.NODE_ENV || "production";

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        filename: "./index.js"
    },
    output: {
        filename: "./build/bundle.js"
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {   test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        contentBase: "public",
        port: 3005
    }
}
```

Comment: Try another port ?

Comment: Tried 3000, 3005, 3015 without luck.

Comment: is there other error messages? on terminal, or on browser console maybe?

Comment: Nothing, nothing in console the page doesnt load at all.

Comment: Weird because same setup works on windows...but on my mac it doesnt maybe a mac issue?

Comment: I'm experiencing the exact same issue. I'm on a mac and webpack dev server pages don't open on chrome. Works on every other browser, though.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and managed to fix it by adding a new register on my `hosts` file:

- open `/etc/hosts` with a text editor with sudo privileged
- add this line to the file:

`127.0.0.1       localhost`

- save and close the file
- go to http://localhost:3005 on Chrome and it should work